# Why $\textrm{span}(S)$ is subspace of $V$, given any $S\subseteq V$ and $V$ a vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I've read the proof of it, but it's still not intuitive for me, so I have to memorize it.

By now, the only one reasonable way to think about it is: *Since $S$ inherits both operations of $V$, and those operations are closed under $V$ and possess those eight properties, so the proof can be done.*

But I'm not sure that whether this is the essential part that $span(S)$ must be a subspace of $V$.

---

The definition of span in my book is:

*Let $S$ be a nonempty subset of a vector space $V$. The **span** of $S$, denoted span($S$), is the set consisting of all linear combinations of the vectors in $S$. For convenience, we define span($\emptyset$)$=\{0\}$.*

Comment: This might be a helpful way to think about it: $U=\text{span}(S)$ is the smallest subspace of $V$ containing $S$. That is, $U$ is the intersection of all subspaces of $V$ that contain $S$. (Can you prove this?)

Comment: Your question suggests to me that you just need to let it rest for a while. It reads like you've studied enough, have all the input/information but are just confused from the overload. Been there many times myself - and will probably go there again ;)

Comment: @polynomial_donut: You're right, I've spent an entire day thinking about this yesterday... Thanks for your caring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The definition of $\operatorname{span}$ is chosen so that the following property holds:

> For any $S\subseteq V$, $\operatorname{span}(S)$ is the smallest subspace of $V$ that contains $S$.

That's really the fundamental aspect of what a span is—if it weren't true for whatever reason, we'd fix the definition of $\operatorname{span}$ to make it work. Since you already understand the technical aspects, I think that's the best answer for how to think of it: if you have a subset but want a subspace instead, $\operatorname{span}$ is the technical gizmo that will do that for you.

Comment: Question: "Why is $span(S)$ a subspace of $V$* Answer: "It is its smallest subspace"... really? ;)